# Marionette.ItemView render event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

It's hard to me to explain what I'm looking for, so I will start with code.

I have Marionette view like this:

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: new Models.Cards(),
    template: 'poker/cards',
    events: {
        'click player': 'playerClicked'
    },
    playerClicked: function( e ) {
        // THIS WORKS!
    }
}
```

How can I do something like this:

```
    events: {
        'click player': 'playerClicked',
        'render player': 'playerRendered'
    },
```

so that `playerRendered` be called when `<player>` is rendered?

Comment: Could you expand your question to include more info about what is going on here, what these objects are, and how they interact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run some code when the `ItemView` itself is rendered, use `onRender`:

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  // ...
  onRender: function() {
    console.log("Rendered the ItemView!")
  }
  //...
})
```

Marionette doesn't have built-in events for *parts* of an `ItemView` being rendered.

Comment: If I have this template: {#myplayers}
<player class="normal" value="{player}" style="{style}"></player>
{/myplayers} - so, list of players, `onRender` will be called when the whole list is rendered. I want to catch event when single player item is rendered

Comment: Another words. During the rendering, I need to change css in few players (not everyone). Only in few particular players. This is why I need single player render event, and not the whole list

Comment: In that case you should use a CollectionView, which renders an ItemView for each player.

Comment: Can you please show, how can I do this in your answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

@joews is right. If you want to react to a specific piece of your ItemView being rendered you should react on the `render` event for the whole ItemView. When you render an ItemView it renders the whole template in memory and then appends it to the DOM as one piece. If you want to render a collection of models then you can use a collection view and each ItemView will be rendered independently.

If you want an example of setting up views with CollectionViews and CompositeViews check out this fiddle of rendering four hands of five cards, all the cards having random values: http://jsfiddle.net/kjdgygy5/